# How can I count values in subset of QuerySet more efficiently using the ORM

Tags: python, django

I have the following django models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

class ProductCount(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=True)
    clicked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I'm trying to get the number of times a single product has been clicked or not for each date entry.

I have succeeded with the following code but obviously it's quite long

```
products = ProductCount.objects.filter(product__owner=owner)
for p in products:
    p = p.product
    for d in products.datetimes("date", "second"):
        rs = ProductCount.objects.filter(product=p, date__year=d.year, date__month=d.month, date__day=d.day,
        date__hour=d.hour, date__minute=d.minute)
        display = rs.count()
        clicked = rs.filter(clicked=True).count()
```

I have tried many things with `distinct`, `annotate(Count())` but I was unable to get the expected output

I want an output such as

```
[
    {
        "product_id": "XXX",
        "dates": [
            {
                "2015-08-28T14:30:07": {
                    "clicked": "N",
                    "view": "M"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to the comment of @Sayse my request is 7time faster

```
for p in products:
    for d in p.productcount_set.datetimes("date", "second"):
        rs = p.productcount_set.filter(date__year=d.year, date__month=d.month, date__day=d.day, date__hour=d.hour, date__minute=d.minute)
        display = rs.count()
        clicked = rs.filter(clicked=True).count()
```

I wonder if I can gain more speed or at least get the `display` and `clicked` values in the same request

Comment: I'm confused as to what your code is trying to do... are you looking for `p.productcount_set.filter(date=date).values('clicked')`? (or with an annotation instead of values at least)

Comment: @sayse if I do `date=date` it will check the date until the millisecond whereas I want to get all the results for each second. I'm taking a look at `_set`

Comment: That was more just a lazy example so i didn't have to type the whole thing :p

Comment: Oh yes I have gained a lot of speed thanks to you